# Batch file script lost in translation to exe?

Tags: batch-file, registry

I have this command in my batch script

> `REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /V "My App" /t REG_SZ /F /D "C:\MyAppPath\MyApp.bat"`

and it works as a bat file in windows7 however when convert it to exe file using the command below,

> `REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /V "My App" /t REG_SZ /F /D "C:\MyAppPath\MyApp.exe"`

Using bat to exe converter,iexpress or advanced converter the program does not start at start up? Somehow the function of the bat command is not translated into the exe file?

Comment: does that .exe when you run it yourself? if it doesn't, then no amount of fiddling with `reg` is going to change that fact.

Comment: Hi! It does run itself and add the key successfully but it just doesn't start when the computer boots.. It suppose to be easy but I can't get it to work

Comment: What about the `"C:\MyAppPath\MyApp.exe"`, launched from e.g. command prompt or from `Win+R` run box, goes well? That's @MarcB's question...

Comment: Yes it works from cmd prompt & the exe file itself as well the keys are definitely registered there I checked using ms config and regedit.. It just doesn't start when windows starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys got it to work by disabling UAC